# Delete specific rows using range function

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete all rows in excel sheet if specific column value starts with 1.

For example, if range of `A1:A` having values starts with 1 then I want to delete all those rows using excel vba.

How to get it?

```
  Dim c As Range
Dim SrchRng

 Set SrchRng = Sheets("Output").UsedRange
Do
   Set c = SrchRng.Find("For Men", LookIn:=xlValues)
  If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
Loop While Not c Is Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the required code with comments on how it works. Feed the worksheet and column number to the sub and call it e.g. Delete Rows 2, Sheets("myWorksheet"):

```
   Sub DeleteRows(columnNumber as Integer, ws as WorkSheet)

    Dim x as long, lastRow as Long

    ' get the last used row
    lastRow = ws.cells(1000000, columnNumber).end(xlUp).Row

    'loop backwards from the last row and delete applicable rows
    For x = lastRow to 1 Step -1

       ' if the cell starts with a number...
       If IsNumeric(Left(ws.Cells(x, columnNumber), 1) Then
          'Delete it the row if it's equaal to 1
          If Left(ws.Cells(x, columnNumber), 1) = 1 Then ws.Rows(x &":"& x).Delete
       End If
    Next x

    End Sub
```

Comment: Note that the part `lastRow = ws.cells(1000000, columnNumber).end(xlUp).Row` only selects the last from the first million. You should look at the [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20314755) which doesn't have that problem.

Comment: The usual method is to use `ws.rows.count` rather than a hard coded number to start at the last row.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Value As String
Dim CellName As String
Dim RowNumber As Long
Do While Value <> ""
    CellName = "A" + RowNumber
    Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(GetRowNumber(CellName), GetColumnNumber(CellName)).Value
    If Mid(Value, 1, 1) = "2" Then
       ActiveSheet.Range("A" & RowNumber).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
Loop

Private Function GetColumnNumber(ByVal CellName As String) As Long
    For L = 1 To 26
        If Left(CellName, 1) = Chr(L + 64) Then
            GetColumnNumber = L
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
Private Function GetRowNumber(ByVal CellName As String) As Long
    GetRowNumber = CLng(Mid(CellName, 2))
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

You may be pushing the bounds of what is reasonable to do in Excel vba.

Consider importing the Excel file into Microsoft Access.

Then, you can write 2 Delete Queries and they will run uber fast:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE col1 like '2*'

DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE col2 LIKE '*for men*' OR col3 LIKE '*for men*'
```

After deleting those records, you can export the data to a new Excel file.

Also, you can write an Access Macro to import the Excel File, run the Delete Queries, and Export the data back to Excel.

And you can do all of this without writing a line of VBA Code.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
Sub delete()
    tamano = Range("J2") ' Value into J2
    ifrom = 7 ' where you want to delete
    'Borramos las celdas
    'Delete column A , B and C
    For i = ifrom To tamano
    Range("A" & i).Value = ""
    Range("B" & i).Value = ""
    Range("C" & i).Value = ""
    Next i
End Sub
```